# Invoke SQL Server 2008 stored procedure from Java and mapping POJO with Custom Database type

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc, user-defined-types

I have declared a UDT (User Defined Types) say CustomType in SQL server 2008. I am using this Data type as an IN parameter for a Stored
procedure. I want to call this procedure from a Java class.
To do this I have done the following:

Created a class called CustomType which implements SQLData

```
public class CustomType implements SQLData {

String name ;
int year ;
String sql_type = "CustomType_t";

public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
return sql_type;
}

public void readSQL(SQLInput arg0, String type) throws SQLException {
sql_type = type;
name = arg0.readString() ;
year = arg0.readInt() ;

}


public void writeSQL(SQLOutput arg0) throws SQLException {
arg0.writeString(name) ;
arg0.writeInt(year) ;

}



}
```

My main Java class looks like this:

```
public class Proc2Test {


public static void main(String[] args) {
msmsqlTest() ;
}

public static void msmsqlTest()
{

Connection con = null ;
CallableStatement cStatement = null ;
ResultSet rs = null ;
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=testDB;username=abc;password=xyz";
String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
try
{
Class.forName(driver);
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
java.util.Map map = con.getTypeMap();
map.put("CustomType",
Class.forName("com..test.CustomType"));


con.setTypeMap(map);



cStatement = con.prepareCall("{call abc2(?,?)}") ;

CustomType x = new CustomType() ;

x.name = "ABC" ;
x.year = 20 ;

cStatement.setObject("para1", x, java.sql.Types.OTHER);
cStatement.registerOutParameter(2,Types.INTEGER) ;
rs = cStatement.executeQuery();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
ex.printStackTrace() ;
}


}
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following exception:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This operation is not supported.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.NotImplemented(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.setTypeMap(Unknown Source)
at com.mindcraft.test.Proc2Test.msmsqlTest(Proc2Test.java:97)
at com.mindcraft.test.Proc2Test.main(Proc2Test.java:22)
```

This exception occurs at con.setTypeMap(map)

My problem is how do I call a stored procedure of SQL Server whose input parameter is a custom Database type?
How do I map a POJO with custom database type of SQL Server 2008 and send that to the stored proc?
Does SQL Server 2008 JDBC driver implement `Connection.setTypeMap()` method?